# For loop doesn't work in C++

Tags: c++

The for loop length property for arrays doesn't seem to work for me code

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char a[] = {"H", "e", "l", "l", "o"};
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        std::cout << a[i];
        //I also tried printf with stdlib.h
    }
}
```

But it gives an error. Did I do it right?

Comment: There is no `.length` on arrays in C++. That's a Java thing. I'd recommend checking out [one of these books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: No, you didn't do it right. You invented it!

Answer (score 3):

You are using an array. It is a primitive type. So there are not member functions on it like objects. You have to use a vector instead.  You also have to initialize the vector (or array) with chars not strings.

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<char> a = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size (); i++)
    {
        std::cout << a[i];
    }
}
```

If you really want to use an array you have to define the size function as follow:

```
template<class T, size_t N>
constexpr size_t size (T (&)[N]) { return N; }

int main()
{
    char a[] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
    for (int i = 0; i < size (a); i++)
    {
        std::cout << a[i];
        //I also tried printf with stdlib.h
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the length of an array in c++ you can use:

```
int length = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
```

Array is not an object in c++ thus it cannot have fields.

Answer (score 2):

Plain arrays define no functions but you can use the library `begin` and `end` functions introduced with c++11:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char a[] = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' };  // use chars instead of strings
    for (auto it = std::begin(a); it != std::end(a); ++it)  // use iterators
    {
        std::cout << *it;
    }
}
```

[Run on ideone.](https://ideone.com/7Hf2vC)

Or even shorter using a range for as pointed out by BarryTheHatchet:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char a[] = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' };
    for (auto c : a)
    {
        std::cout << c;
    }
}
```

[Run on ideone.](https://ideone.com/3tUMVn)

Keep in mind that the list initialization as above doesn't include a NULL char. If you declare your array with a NULL char at the end you can use cout directly without for loop:

```
char a[] = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' };  // explicit NULL with list initialization
std::cout << a;

char b[] = "Hello";  // implicit NULL when using a literal
std::cout << b;
```

Comment: Your first example is extremely verbose. Why not simply `for (auto x : a)`?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. You can get the size of an array `a` using:

```
   sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
```

But since you are in C++ you should use an `std::vector` like this:

```
  std::vector<char> a;
```

And then get the size:

```
 a.size();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a is a character array.. It doesn't have any member called `"length"`..This member is found in Java not C++. For this problem you can use `"sizeof()" function` function.